# How to express uncertainty on a measurement with bounded range of values, like humidity, or level in a tank

Tags: uncertainty, measurement

Could someone provide some hints on how to express the uncertainty on a measured quantity like humidity, or level of a liquid in a tank?  Assuming the instruments provide a more or less constant measurement uncertainty over the range of possible values, there is the trouble that there is a hard limit at both ends of the scale: humidity varies between 0 and 100%, and liquid content in a 20-litre tank varies between 0 and 20.

Focusing on the tank, the gauge on the tank may have a specified accuracy of +/- 2 litres, k=2.  This is interpreted as a normal symmetric distribution around the reading which is fine over most of the range, but I know the true value cannot be more than 20, so as the reading increases toward 20, the distribution must become more and more skewed, or so it seems.

- How can I express this?

Now I want to calculate the mass of the liquid by multiplying volume and density of 1 kg/l +/- 5%.

- How can I propagate this?

(I'm generally trying to follow the rules of the GUM.)

Comment: If there is a better place to post this, please let me know!

Comment: This would be the place to post a clearer version of the question with a few numerical examples of what you mean by "uncertainty." And by "limited range," I guess you mean "limited range of time." Can you elaborate on that. // Two humidity measurements may be different at the same time and place due to measurement errors, different at nearby places due to lake or AC exhaust, different at successive times due to change in temp or arrival of fog. Which kinds of variability are important in your application?

Comment: Thanks @BruceET.  I hope the edits are make it much clearer.

Comment: You need to start with a statistical model of the quantity: that will determine appropriate answers.

Comment: Isn't that kind of rewording my question? "Express uncertainty" ~= "statistical model"?  (Consider me a beginner.)

Comment: It is not a mere rewording: it is a request for you to supply essential information.

Comment: Sure, I'll do my best.  Could you explain in another way what information you would be looking for?

Comment: A statistical model!